# Moments of inertia: is there equivalence in moments of inertia about rotational and stationary coordinates in a cylindrical system?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, symmetry, rotational-kinematics, moment-of-inertia

I am looking at a rotational system described by stationary (x, y ,z) and rotary reference frames (i, j, k). Below is a figure attached for reference. The description I am looking at outlines the torque balance equations as follows:

$$ 
I_{i}\ddot{\theta_x} = -\omega_{rm}I_{k}\dot{\theta_{y}} + N_{x}
$$
$$
I_{j}\ddot{\theta_y} = \omega_{rm}I_{k}\dot{\theta_{x}} + N_{y} 
$$

Where $-\omega_{rm}I_{k}\dot{\theta_{y}}$ and $\omega_{rm}I_{k}\dot{\theta_{x}}$ terms describe gyroscopic effects.

Given that the torque balance is done in the $\theta_{x}$ and $\theta_{y}$ direction and, taking the moments of inertia $I_{x}$ and $I_{y}$ makes sense to me. I.e.

$$ 
I_{x}\ddot{\theta_x} = -\omega_{rm}I_{z}\dot{\theta_{y}} + N_{x}
$$
$$
I_{y}\ddot{\theta_y} = \omega_{rm}I_{z}\dot{\theta_{x}} + N_{y} 
$$

However, with the involvement of the $I_{x}$ and $I_{y}$ I feel more uneasy.

I was wondering, if in this system the following is true? And is this the assumption that the first two equations are built on?

$$ 
I_{x} = I_{i}
$$
$$
I_{y} = I_{j}
$$

My guess is that because the rotary and the stationary co-ordinate systems originate from the same point, they will both be on the plane of the shafts rotation, hence making the moments of inertia about i and x (for example) equal - am I getting the right idea?

[image: Rotor system]

Answer (score 0):

starting with the Euler equation

$$\mathbf\Theta\,\mathbf{\dot{\omega}}+\mathbf\omega\times(\mathbf\Theta\,\mathbf\omega)=\mathbf\tau\tag 1$$

with

$$\mathbf\omega=
 \begin{bmatrix}
   \omega_x \\
   \omega_y \\
   0 \\
 \end{bmatrix}+
 {\Omega}\begin{bmatrix}
           k_x \\
           k_y \\
           k_z \\
         \end{bmatrix}\quad\text{with }~\mathbf k\cdot\mathbf k=1
$$

$$\mathbf\Theta=\begin{bmatrix}
    I_x & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & I_y & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & I_z \\
  \end{bmatrix}\quad,I_y=I_x\quad\text{because the symmetry }$$

and
$$\mathbf\tau=\begin{bmatrix}
   \tau_x \\
   \tau_y \\
   0 \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

you obtain from equation (1)

$$I_x\dot\omega_x=k_z\,k_y\,(I_x-I_z)\,\Omega^2+k_z\,\omega_y\,(I_x-I_z)\Omega+\tau_x$$

$$I_y\dot\omega_y=-k_z\,k_x\,(I_x-I_z)\,\Omega^2-k_z\,\omega_x\,(I_x-I_z)\Omega+\tau_x$$

for the linear case is
$$\omega=\dot\theta\quad \dot\omega=\ddot\theta$$